# Microsoft Azure Blob storage update

Tags: powershell, azure, blob

Is there any way to update an Azura Blob Storage by scripts?

I can write a PowerShell script that deletes the actual content of a Blob storage and then upload the content again (obviously, with the changes I made in the meantime), but to avoid this tedious and data-consuming process, is there any better solution to compare the content uploaded and only upload files which are changed? I have seen some solutions in C# but I'd like to use PS script. Thanks for the recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit after comments**:

Think you could be after Append Blobs:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee691964.aspx

I believe it can only be applied to a specific storage blob type

Comment: Thing is, this still actually overwrites existing files which I don't really want, all I need is to get new content uploaded and old content untouched. I'll try to find a workaround for this, thanks anyway :)

Comment: Thanks for the edition, will have a look at it, although the blob type's is not up to me but my company :)